# Approximate arbitrary distribution with a Gaussian Mixture

Tags: probability-distributions, nonlinear-optimization, gaussian

I saw the claim that a Gaussian mixture is a universal approximator of densities [here](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/prob.html).
I am trying to implement that to approximate an arbitrary distribution, for example, a univariate bounded uniform distribution $pdf=1/(b-a): [a,b]$ and $pdf=0:$ else.

The only way I thought about doing this is with a nonlinear optimization program (like *fminsearch* in Matlab) on the squared error from the true distribution ($L_2$-norm). The problem is that it highly depends on the initialization of the parameters ($\gamma_i, \mu_i, \sigma_i$) and I get various results. I'll attach the code here at the bottom, although, it is not really the issue. I'd like to know if there's a better, or maybe some analytic way to approximate a distribution. For example, how is the claim "*can be approximated with any speciﬁc nonzero amount of error*" reconciled here when I can't control the actual error? (I know my example isn't smooth).

Thank you.

```
% just an example
params0 = [1/3, 1, 1 , ...
           1/3, 1, 1, ...
           1/3, 1., 1];
[params,fval] = fminsearch(@distrib_gaussian_mixture,params0);

% the function to call, some "tricks" are here to avoid the need for a constrained program
function dist = distrib_gaussian_mixture(params)
    k = size(params,1);
    x = -3:0.01:3;
    pdf = 0*x;
    true_pdf = pdf;
    true_pdf(350:450)=1;
    true_pdf = true_pdf / norm(true_pdf);
    
    for i=1:k
        gamma = abs(params(i,1));
        mu = params(i,2);
        sigma = abs(params(i,3));
        pdf = pdf + gamma * normpdf(x, mu, sigma);
    end
    pdf = pdf / norm(pdf);
    
    dist = norm(pdf-true_pdf);
```

**EDIT**:

I found that Matlab has a function called *fitgmdist* which basically does what I want. The problem is that it is making it in a weird way - instead of approximating the pdf, I need to create random samples from the pdf, and it approximates from that data (not very convenient but more importantly it will vary the results a little bit).

I would close my question, though I do not really have an answer for how to guarantee the error bounds (other than iterating the number of mixands until I get it).

Comment: Two thoughts: Firstly though the source you cite does not give a proof of the fact that gaussian mixtures are approximators it seems to me like an application of Stone-Weierstrass. I at least have a proof sketched out in my head. Unfortunately, Stone-Weierstrass only gives the existence of an approximating sequence but not a construction of the sequence nor bound on the rate of convergence. Also the rate of convergence might depend on the distance one is using; you for example are using a distance that looks like the total variation distance.

Comment: Secondly, the way the built-in function tries to approximate the pdf is what I would do at first thought. Given a sample $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim \nu$, the empirical measure, $\nu_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum \delta_{X_i}$ is supposed to converge to the sampled measure $\nu$ (given some assumptions in the Wasserstein metrics, I think). Thus an approximation by a gaussian mixture with means $X_1, \dots, X_n$ and some variances is a smooth approximation of the empirical measure: $\varphi_{0, \sigma^2} \star \nu_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum \varphi_{X_n, \sigma^2}$.

Comment: Agree that the source you cited didn't give a proof to this claim